# Template style only partially applied by PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

Problem with PHPSpreadsheet. When I read my own template file and opened the saved one, the template style was applied only to the first row or column, and the rest of the cells became the default style. I want the template style to be applied to all cells.

The executed code is as follows.

```
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('sample.xlsx');

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('write.xlsx');

exit();
```

Maybe not a code issue, but a spreadsheet issue. If you have a similar problem, I'd like to give some advice so I can do it a little.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The styles will not automatically taken from the template. You can set them manually.
Take a look to [Documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#styles).
Not all kind of styles are implemented. Pivot-Tables for example aren't supported. If you use format as table you use an pivot-table and yes this is not supported as well.